# Calculate a value based on array index and include it into JSON using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON with the form:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "createDate": "6/10/2016 6:12:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "7/10/2016 1:00:00 AM",
    "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
    "notes": "corrected spelling error"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "createDate": "8/09/2016 3:15:55 PM",
    "reviewDate": "7/10/2016 1:00:00 AM",
    "reviewedBy": "John Wayne",
    "notes": "corrected spelling error"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "createDate": "8/09/2016 3:15:55 PM",
    "reviewDate": "3/12/2016 12:00:00 PM",
    "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
    "notes": "finished"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "17/10/2017 1:00:00 AM",
    "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
    "notes": "changed location"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "13/12/2017 12:00:00 PM",
    "reviewedBy": "John Wayne",
    "notes": "consider additional control measures"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "createDate": "26/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "13/01/2018 12:00:00 PM",
    "reviewedBy": "Susan Port",
    "notes": "finished"
  }
]
```

I want to add an item to make it look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "seq": "1",
    "createDate": "6/10/2016 6:12:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "7/10/2016 1:00:00 AM",
    "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
    "notes": "corrected spelling error"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "seq": "1",
    "createDate": "8/09/2016 3:15:55 PM",
    "reviewDate": "7/10/2016 1:00:00 AM",
    "reviewedBy": "John Wayne",
    "notes": "corrected spelling error"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "seq": "2",
    "createDate": "8/09/2016 3:15:55 PM",
    "reviewDate": "3/12/2016 12:00:00 PM",
    "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
    "notes": "finished"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "seq": "1",
    "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "17/10/2017 1:00:00 AM",
    "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
    "notes": "changed location"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "seq": "2",
    "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "13/12/2017 12:00:00 PM",
    "reviewedBy": "John Wayne",
    "notes": "consider additional control measures"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "seq": "3",
    "createDate": "26/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "reviewDate": "13/01/2018 12:00:00 PM",
    "reviewedBy": "Susan Port",
    "notes": "finished"
  }
]
```

So far, I've been able to group the data by the value of "id":

```json
[
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "createDate": "6/10/2016 6:12:33 PM",
      "reviewDate": "7/10/2016 1:00:00 AM",
      "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
      "notes": "corrected spelling error"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "createDate": "8/09/2016 3:15:55 PM",
      "reviewDate": "7/10/2016 1:00:00 AM",
      "reviewedBy": "John Wayne",
      "notes": "corrected spelling error"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "createDate": "8/09/2016 3:15:55 PM",
      "reviewDate": "3/12/2016 12:00:00 PM",
      "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
      "notes": "finished"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "6",
      "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
      "reviewDate": "17/10/2017 1:00:00 AM",
      "reviewedBy": "Dave Smith",
      "notes": "changed location"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
      "reviewDate": "13/12/2017 12:00:00 PM",
      "reviewedBy": "John Wayne",
      "notes": "consider additional control measures"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "createDate": "26/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
      "reviewDate": "13/01/2018 12:00:00 PM",
      "reviewedBy": "Susan Port",
      "notes": "finished"
    }
  ]
]
```

By using:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@id[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now, I haven't been able to figure how to calculate a seq value for each element in each array and then split each array.

I was able to do it separately using:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].id",
        "createDate": "[&1].createDate",
        "reviewDate": "[&1].reviewDate",
        "notes": "[&1].notes",
        "$": "[&1].seq"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And I get:

```json
[
  {
    "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "id": "6",
    "notes": "changed location",
    "reviewDate": "17/10/2017 1:00:00 AM",
    "seq": "0"
  },
  {
    "createDate": "16/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "id": "6",
    "notes": "consider additional control measures",
    "reviewDate": "13/12/2017 12:00:00 PM",
    "seq": "1"
  },
  {
    "createDate": "26/10/2017 1:08:33 PM",
    "id": "6",
    "notes": "finished",
    "reviewDate": "13/01/2018 12:00:00 PM",
    "seq": "2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should group by the "id" values. You can retry with the following transformation :

```json
[
  { // group by the "id" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,id.&[]"
      }
    }
  },
  { // generate seq values as ordinals 0,1,2 ... for each group
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": {
          "@": "&2.id", // to keep the "id" values
          "*": { // while generating "seq" values
            "$": "&3.seq_[]"
          }
        },
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // flatten all of the arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the objects labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  { // increment the "sq" values by 1
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "seq_": "=intSum(@(1,&),1)",
        "seq": "=toString(@(1,seq_))"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the auxiliary attribute "seq_"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "seq_": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros for your prompt response. The output is close to what I'm looking for.<br/>I'm getting a new 'seq' item with what it seems to be the number of elements per group i.e. "seq" : 2 for the two elements where "id" : "5" as opposed to  "seq" : 1 for the first element and  "seq" : 2 for the second.

Comment: OK @OmarBeltranRodriguez , realised that I missed the point, I've edited just now. Take care.

Comment: Awesome @Barbaros, it works perfectly. Thanks.